# If the Continuum's cardinality could physically change because of a physical manifestation of forcing

Tags: logic, truth, set-theory

Suppose that the Continuum has a specific cardinality assigned to it when it exists "in" a physical universe. (This, or a similar-sounding supposition, occurs frequently enough in the literature.) But suppose also that forcing (as introduced by Cohen and expanded upon by others) corresponds to a physical phenomenon, one involving a change in the physical Continuum's cardinality. I would imagine that the "tendency" for physical systems to try to use the least energy/follow the shortest path might be exemplified, here, in the "ground state" for the physical Continuum being the cardinality assignment that it would take the "least amount of energy"/"shortest path" to reach, viz. physically, the Continuum tends to be ℵ<sub>1</sub>. (We don't have to frame this as a process singling out just the Continuum, though; we could frame it as the universe "preferring" *L* and its rules, *L* being the minimum such object, hence the object it requires the "least energy" to conform to; but *V = L* leads to GCH which "confirms" CH by default.)

**My question is**: [Jan Łukasiewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_%C5%81ukasiewicz) developed an ℵ<sub>0</sub>-valued logic, which led to [fuzzy logic's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-fuzzy/) ℝ-valued logic (in the interval [0, 1]).<sup>☾</sup> If the number of elements of ℝ (and its intervals) can change, wouldn't this mean that the number of truth values in our world could change? What would it mean for this change to take place? {Alternatively, and to avoid the fringe-science flavor of the preceding: what does the variability of the ZFC Continuum mean for fuzzy logic, anyway?}

<sup>☾</sup><sub>Subquestion: suppose a truth function (*S*) on sentences *S*. Why should the range of the function be the real interval [0, 1]? Why not allow negative values and values greater than 1? On an electronic calculator, you can get results like "undefined" and "invalid expression"; are these expressions "false" or "*worse*"? Or, theologically, if God is beyond existence and nonexistence, if univocal descriptions are broadly contraindicated, then wouldn't we be tempted to say that true *S* about God are "supertrue," i.e. that (*G*) > 1, for *G* a positive/substantial God-involving sentence, when (and of course only when) *G* is "supertrue"? (Then Cantor's opinion on the matter can be represented as: assume that *V* is anti-zero, the universal number; then we have that ("God exists") = *V*, and indeed all supertruths of the divine nature are absolutely infinitely supertrue.)</sub>

Comment: What about posing this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?

Comment: Most of the questions I've asked there were downvoted into negative numbers, and at one point the site itself was like, "You don't have a reputation for asking good enough questions to ask any new ones, here." I have a better reputation on the MathOverflow [somehow!], but at any rate I don't think they'd take kindly to a physicalistic interpretation of forcing. They might not disagree *per se* with the possibility so much as doubt that the idea is purely mathematically tractable.

Comment: I don't even know what it would mean for the continuum to have a specific cardinality in the physical universe. Points aren't physical things, nor are numbers. What else could you be counting in this physical continuum that would have a transfinite number? Real numbers were invented to arithmetize geometry (or, arguably, to make algebra more complete). It is a purely mathematical notion.

Comment: In my opinion, it is okay to suggest some novel idea when asking something, but what I've experienced is that most of mathematicians prefer shorter question over longer questions. I don't think any other researchers in another field would differ much from mathematicians. I am sure that you would get much better response when you can make your question shorter.

Comment: Does it make sense to have a “fixed” cardinality to the (physical) universe at some time while allowing forcing generating new physical cardinalities? It’d be like the universe is able to grow itself while remaining a totality and infinite. *Maybe so*, it seems similar to how the universe expands via dark energy

Comment: "But suppose also that forcing ...  corresponds to a physical phenomenon ..." I confess I find this suggestion utterly bizarre. Can you give an example of what you might be talking about? Are you coming at this from a naive or an expert knowledge of forcing? ie, Wikipedia or grad-level set theory? Either way it's "not even wrong." In my opinion of course. Can you put this in better context?

Comment: @user4894, I'm thinking in terms of a mix of Hamkins/Loewe's(?) modal logic of forcing and Paul Corazza's analogy between his "critical point dynamics" and quantum field theory. But like I said in the OP, if, "The number of points in physical space changes," sounds too warped to address, I just wonder what the intersection is of fuzzy truth value theory, and paracomplete/pluralist options for the Continuum's cardinality.

Comment: @KristianBerry I looked up Hamkins's summary here. http://jdh.hamkins.org/themodallogicofforcing/ Can you explain how these ideas have the slightest bearing on the ultimate nature of the physical world?

Comment: I confess, I was considering a Tegmarkesque background, where set-theoretic universes are like the *a priori* forms of physical universes, so the diversity of set-theoretic worlds is reflected in the diversity of possible concrete worlds. Then there are different possible physical worlds whose Continua differ in size. But if there is a Smolin world (where the laws of physics change over time), a conjecture I'm entertaining is that this change might involve a specific Continuum itself fluctuating over time.

Comment: @KristianBerry I find it difficult to take these kinds of speculations seriously. I genuinely doubt that set theory applies to the physical world. And it's an open question as to whether the spacetime continuum, as it's colloquially called, is an actual mathematical continuum. The real numbers are very unlikely IMO to truly model space. So, what do you think about large cardinals? Might they be physically instantiated to? Like I say, I consider talk like this trolling, but I get that you are serious. FWIW I think Tegmark's trolling too. He can't possibly mean what he wrote.

Comment: @KristianBerry More grist for your mill. If the mathematical real numbers are physically instantiated, what do we make of the fact that almost all real numbers are noncomputable? Then the universe can not possibly be a computation and neither can the human mind. If the real numbers have physical existence, it blows up the computational theory of mind. Or perhaps the universe instantiates the *intuitionistic* or *constructive* real lines. That solves the computability problem, at least.

Comment: I didn't follow his metaphysical argument as well as I could've, but Paul Corazza in [this essay](http://pcorazza.lisco.com/papers/corazza_infinityQFTLarge.pdf) tries to connect up the theory of elementary embeddings (which is the modern standard-bearer for the large-cardinal ascent) with quantum field theory. It reminded me of an article on a Kant subtopic, in the SEP, where the guy tried to relate noumena to Calabi-Yau manifolds or something. So, IDK. At any rate, the idea that something in the physical world has a transfinite signature that changes, keeps showing up in my notes...

Comment: @KristianBerry Have you seen Massimo Pigliucci's article, "Mathematical Universe? I Ain’t Convinced"? When pressed, Tegmark retreats to the Computable universe hypothesis. And when pressed further, he denies infinite sets altogether! I do not believe that you can invoke higher transfinite cardinalities in the same discussion as Tegmark's mathematical universe hypothesis.  Tegmark himself, when pressed on the issue, retreats from transfinite cardinalities.https://www.science20.com/rationally_speaking/mathematical_universe_i_ain%e2%80%99t_convinced-127841

Comment: @KristianBerry I didn't see your reply before my last comment. Thanks for that article. I'm interested in people trying to relate transfinite set theory to physics, there's very little in the literature and even less that's not behind an academic paywall. I've had the thought that if the universe instantiates an infinite set, then the Continuum hypothesis becomes a problem subject to physical experiment.